# Resolving Higher/Lower level component dependency

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, object-oriented-design, component

I have a .NET application (actually this can be a problem for any N-Tiered application) which has 3 separate components.

- ClassLibrary

  - Has Cross Cutting Concerns like logging, authentication and IoC resolving.
  - Has static Utility classes for Encoding/Decoding, Encryption etc.
- ThirdPartyApps

  - Has external library references like YouTube, Azure, AWS nuget packages and libraries.
  - References to ClassLibrary to use logging and static utility classes.
- Background Application

  - Also references to Class Library.
  - Includes logic to utilize ThirdParty Apps, such as consuming YoutubeAPI

My problem in here, from Background Application, I do not want do direct reference to ThirdPartyApps. Because, I want ClassLibrary to resolve provider I want (from ThirdPartyApps).

But I cannot register ThirdPartyApps in ClassLibrary with Autofac (IoC container), because ClassLibrary already referenced by ThirdPartyApps, so it will create "Circular Dependency Error".

Seems like I am missing an implementation logic here, and would like to see what would be a possible way to resolve it.

I am thinking to create another component for dependency mapping, but I do not want to create unnecessary extra component for no reason (or maybe this will be the solution?).

Is there any wrong logic I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (or maybe this will be the solution?)"

Yes, go and create another component, of course. And that component is not unnecessary. If you don't want to create a "big ball of mud", where everything depends on everything else, you will be happy that you don't need to bind your existing ClassLibrary to the `ThirdPartyApps` component directly.